# Is it possible to force Pervasive to not attempt IPv6 connections?

Tags: c#, ipv6, ipv4, pervasive, pervasive-sql

Through the use of a profiler, I have noticed that as we making connections to a Pervasive database, the engine always throws a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` which reads:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:1583

...and it has just this little stack trace:

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

Apparently, the Pervasive database engine is always attempting the IPv6 version of `localhost` (the server in this case) first and failing before falling back to the IPv4 connection and succeeding.  So the illusion of success is maintained, but a lot of exceptions are consumed in the process.

But in my opinion, having to consume an exception for *every* attempted connection just plain stinks.

Is this the normal way of doing things?  Or is there some way I can force the use of IPv4, ignoring IPv6?  Please note that any answer that ends in "turn it off in Windows" isn't viable.  If I can't control this in code, I'll just have to live with it.

I suspect the first retort will be, "what if the client wants, needs, or at least can use IPv6?".  Honestly, I don't know.  I'll take any advice on this topic, as networking isn't my strong suit.  But I would agree with the notion that if IPv6 is available, it probably should be used.

However, the main point I am trying to make is that when IPv6 isn't available, my code is forced to eat a ton of exceptions, and that bothers me.

Just for the sake of showing something, here's what it looks like in code:

```
private PsqlConnection _connection = new PsqlConnection();
_connection.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};ServerDSN={1}", _serverName, _dbName);
try { _connection.Open(); }
catch (Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlException ex) { /*write Pervasive-specific error to log*/ }
catch (Exception ex) { /*write generic error to log*/ }
```

The `try` block around the `Open()` call is never actually hit.  It seems that it's bubbling up, and I can break on it, but it's handled deeper in.  Neither `catch` is actually hit.

Comment: In my experience Pervasive is a pain... thank god the company I work for migrated away from it and OPF3 to SQL Server and Entity Framework.

Comment: Every hostname should resolve to addresses that actually work. If there is a mismatch then you'll always get annoying exceptions like this. I.e. if localhost resolves to both 127.0.0.1 and ::1 then both should work. If they don't then either change the DNS or local resolver data, or adjust the system settings / firewall settings to make them both work.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Your point is well taken, but my concern is whether or not there is a more graceful, and generic, means of dealing with the situation, instead of per-machine configuration changes.

Comment: Machines have to be configured correctly. If not then all that's left is error/exception handling...

Comment: You've got it backwards. The server _should be_ configured to listen on IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

In your connection string set EnableIPV6 to false...

[Taken from here... Table 27](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=adonet/objintrf.08.3.html)
"
Provides backward compatibility for connecting to the Pervasive Server using an IPv4 address.

If set to True, a client with IPv6 protocol installed can identify itself to the server using either an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address.

If set to False, the clients runs in the backward compatibility mode. The client always identifies itself to the server using an IPv4 address.

The default value for 4.0 is set to True, while the default value for 3.5 is set to False. This option is not valid for 3.2

To ensure that users who connect to Pervasive Server using VPN do not get credited with the use of an additional license, Pervasive recommends that users of Data Provider 3.5 set EnableIPv6 to True.
"

**UPDATE:**
Have you examined the InfoMessage event?...
"
You can use the InfoMessage event of the PsqlConnection object to retrieve warnings and informational messages from the database. If the database returns an error, an exception is thrown.

Clients that want to process warnings and informational messages sent by the database server should create a PsqlInfoMessageEventHandler delegate to register for this event.

The InfoMessage event receives an argument of type PsqlInfoMessageEventArgs containing data relevant to this event.
"

Comment: Unfortunately, that keyword is not available.  I am using `Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.dll` version 3.5.0.1820.  I note that I might be using SP2 and that documentation reads "SP3".

Comment: If you can't update it then I'd say good luck in trying to find an alternative.

Comment: I'm striking out at every swing.  Wired up a handler for `InfoMessage`, and it never hit.  I get 3+ `SocketExceptions` but no InfoMessage was ever received.  Strange.  Thanks for that tip, though.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Last stab... is there a property like  FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors of the _connection, if so try setting it to true... I remember reading somewhere; something like < lvl 10 errors comeback as infomessage, >= 10 throw exceptions... When you set FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors to true, errors that were previously treated as exceptions are now handled as InfoMessage events. All events fire immediately and are handled by the event handler. If is FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors is set to false, then InfoMessage events are handled at the end of the procedure.

Comment: Looks like `PsqlConnection` inherits from `DbConnection` and not `SqlConnection`, and it's the latter in which that property exists.  Apparently, `DbConnection` doesn't even support it, so Pervasive must be providing it on their own.  Anyone's guess why it doesn't shoot messages, I guess.  Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: This might be validation that SP3 is required in order to use the `EnableIPV6` connection string parameter:  http://support.pervasive.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/Database_KnowledgeBase/article-id/1834.  I'll be looking into that later.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.... in a Pervasive way :D ... gl! "Pervasive as an adjective = (especially of an unwelcome influence or physical effect) spreading widely throughout an area or a group of people."... unwelcome being the keyword :D